# Adding some common methods to different classes

Tags: delphi, controls, delphi-10.3-rio

I have the following structure... Three controls made by me, that inherit from the same common control `TCustomControl`.

```
TDriveBar [MyShell.pas] > TCustomPanel [Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas] > TCustomControl [Vcl.Controls.pas]...

TPathBar [MyShell.pas] > TCustomControl [Vcl.Controls.pas]...

TFileList [MyShell.pas] > TCustomSuperList [MySuperList.pas] > TCustomControl [Vcl.Controls.pas]...
```

Now, I would like to change something so that my `TDriveBar`, `TPathBar` and `TFileList` can be accessed (typecast) as a common ancestor class and have some new methods in common. That ancestor seems to be `TCustomControl`, but I don't know if it's possible to insert a new class there. Even more, I would prefer that `TCustomSuperList` not to contain those new methods when it's used alone. I don't know if I made myself understood...

I cannot use interfaces because the idea is to write the common methods only once and use them in those thre controls... With an interface, I have to implement it in every Shell control...

Comment: I don't see how what you're asking would work, because neither `TDriveBar` or `TFileList` descends directly from `TCustomControl`; `TDriveBar` descends from `TCustomPanel`, and `TFileList` descends from `TCustomSuperList`. You can't inject a new class between `TCustomControl` and `TCustomPanel`, and the same thing applies to `TFileList`.

Comment: Single inheritance says no

Comment: Without interfaces, this is simply not possible.  However, there is nothing preventing you from writing a standalone set of functions or a helper class to implement the common functionality, and then you can have each component implement the common interface and internally delegate its implementation to the common functions/class.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But if I do that, I cannot acces the properties of my control from the interface methods, isn't it ? I think that I must implement the interface in all three controls...

Comment: @MarusNebunu yes, you can. Simply pass in the control's `Self` pointer as a parameter to the object/functions that implement the interface methods. Yes, you have to implement the interface in all three controls, but you can delegate that implementation elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Delphi has the ability to delegate the methods of an interface to another object using the keyword [implements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_Implements_for_Delegation).

In your case, the idea is to create an object implementing an interface with the common methods and in each of your components you create a property having the interface type and delegated to the object.